# How Can I configure separate resilience4j circuit breaker for each instance registered under the SAME Eureka service

Tags: spring-cloud, resilience4j, openfeign

Here is my scenario:

Eureka Server: MY-APP-SERVICE with 3 instances of same spring boot app running on e.g localhost:8080, localhost:8081 and localhost:8082

OpenFeign client (Annotated as follow)

```
@FeignClient(name="MY-APP-SERVICE")
public interface MyFeignClient {...}
```

I have a proxy controller e.g. MyAppServiceClientController as follow:

```
@RestController
public class MyAppServiceClientController {
   Autowired
   MyFeignClient myFeignClient;

   @CircuitBreaker(name = "backendA")
   public String doSomething() {
      return myFeignClient.doSomething();
   }
}
```

When FeignClient asks Eureka registry for the service MY-APP-SERVICE it gets all 3 instances; it seems like resilience4j has only 1 circuit breaker at service level, here MY-APP-SERVICE.

How can I configure/annotate my FeignClient to have a separate resilience4j circuit breaker for each instance/URL in my MY-APP-SERVICE ?

Comment: circuit breakers are used for services in aggregate, not individual instances.